# Segfault occurs on initialization in pthread only

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, stack

I cannot understand why the following pseudo code is causing a segfault.

Using pthreads to run a function I run into a SEGFAULT initializing an integer to zero.

When `my_threaded_function` not in threaded context or if I called function from the main thread there is no issue.

The SEGFAULT doesn't occur on initializing `rc=0;`bu only inside the `maze_init` function.

I have confirmed that I am out of stack space. But I can't think of what is causing the function to behave differently inside the pthread (no shared memory involved), the address `&aa` cannot be accessed according to gdb.

Why would a stack variable's address not be on the stack?

```
int maze_init(Maze*m, char* filename)
{
   FILE *fp;
   int aa, bb, rc; 
   aa = 0;              /// SEGFAULT HERE
   ...
   return 1; 
}

void* my_threaded_function(void* arg)
{ 
   Maze maze;
   int rc;
   rc = 0;

   rc = maze_init(&maze,"test.txt");
   return rc;
   pthread_exit((void*)1);
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
   pthread_t t;
   pthread_create(&t, NULL, my_threaded_function,(void*)0);
   sleep(10);
}
```

- edit (fixed code typo to `return rc`)

Comment: In your `thread` function i.e. `my_threaded_function`, why are you returning `return rn;` and where is `rn` declared?

Comment: Do you call `maze_init` recursively? What's the definition of `Maze`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson maze is pretty big 1000x1000 chars + some more

Comment: Then you are most likely running out of stack-space. Either increase as described below, or use dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have confirmed that I am out of stack space. But I can't think of
>   what is causing the function to behave differently inside the pthread

Well for one by default secondary threads have smaller stacks than the "main" thread. You can set the size with [`pthread_attr_setstacksize`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setstacksize.html).

[TLPI](http://man7.org/tlpi/) says:

> Each thread has its own stack whose size is fixed when the thread is
>   created. On Linux/x86-32, for all threads other than the main thread,
>   the default size of the per-thread stack is 2 MB. **The main thread has
>   a much larger space for stack growth**

So that is one reason why it would work when called normally and fail when called from a secondary thread.